# how to avoid a loop in a calculation of mean in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix A with size 100000x128.
For each row of this matrix I need to calculate the mean of columns 1:16, 17:32... 98:113.
The way I'm doing it is with a for loop like this:

```
    n = 8; % number of windows
    win_size = 128/n;

    for i = 1 : length(A)
     PAA(i,:) = [mean(reshape(A(i,:),win_size,n))];
    end
```

Any chance I could improve this without the loop?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use reshape, to create another dimension for your blocks:

```
y=reshape(x,size(x,1),win_size,size(x,2)/win_size)
```

To get the mean per block, use `mean(y,2)`

Comment: Thanks. That works very well. I just added:
      meanY = squeeze(mean(y,2));

Answer (score 0):

```
>> A = randn(100000, 128);
>> Amean = reshape(mean(reshape(A',16,100000)), 8, 100000)';
```

Comment: There is a growing trend to mark code-only answers as low-quality.  Best to explain the answer a bit, so that your assumptions are plain... in case they diverge the what the OP intended to ask, or so that another with different needs may benefit more cleanly.